# Rails polymorphic association when tables and the classes are different in two applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I am struggling with something really custom.
I have **Seller** and **Buyer** apps.

In **Seller** I have defined two models with STI, this app have CRUD for Attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class PhotoAttachment < Attachment
end

class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :photo_attachment, as: :owner
end
```

So I have table name `attachments` with records of type value `PhotoAttachment`.

**Buyer** app, have access to database so I have models pointing to same table names:
(I intentionally nested class under **Seller**'s namespace to distinct from **Buyer** app models)
Create reader models:

```
class Seller::Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'attachments'

  # Associations
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true, class_name: 'Seller::Attachment'
end

class Seller::PhotoAttachment < Seller::Attachment
  self.table_name = 'attachments'
end
```

Now, when I am trying to read Buyer app attachment with `Seller::PhotoAttachment.last` I have wrong reading of db:

```
SELECT  `attachments`.* FROM `attachments` WHERE `attachments`.`type` IN ('Seller::PhotoAttachment')
```

However, I need to have selector to read just `WHERE` attachments`.`type `IN ('PhotoAttachment')`

I have tried to find how can I change inheritance or model name when it's generate query but nothing in documentations.

Anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: what version of Rails? This sounds like it could be a Rails bug.

Comment: not sure its a bug. Two different rails applications sharing same DB, `Seller` App write to attachments table with its value of class name(STI). Buyer have nested STI model which should read "non nested" value. I want to customize what value can be in `type` column.
Stored `type` is `PhotoAttachment` value but Buyer App read it as `Seller::PhotoAttachment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a litte more, I found that there is class method `sti_name` in `ActiveRecord::Inheritance` which you can overwrite with your own, so in my case it worked as:

```
class Seller::PhotoAttachment < Seller::Attachment
  self.table_name = 'attachments'

  class << self
    def sti_name
      'PhotoAttachment'
    end
  end
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods/sti_name